# how can I either move or calculate the sum of a deeply nested object's properties to the top level in an object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array like below:

```
const collection = [
    {
      "name": "Top1",
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "shahnshah",
          "data": [
            {
              "name": "test1",
              "values": {
                "val1": 876,
                "val2": 3456
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Alex",
          "data": [
            {
              "name": "test1",
              "values": {
                "val1": 654,
                "val2": 300
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "test2",
              "values": {
                "val1": 676,
                "val2": 888
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Top2",
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "shahnshah",
          "data": [
            {
              "name": "test1",
              "values": {
                "val1": 111,
                "val2": 300
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Alex",
          "data": [
            {
              "name": "test1",
              "values": {
                "val1": 100,
                "val2": 150
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "test2",
              "values": {
                "val1": 600,
                "val2": 50
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

I'm trying to convert this data in a format where I can show this one in a table with total values for keys "val1", "val2" added in the top level of their corresponding top level keys ( i.e. name). The end result I'm expecting is something like this.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Top1",
        
        // Only these two values will be extra
        "val1": 2206, // "val1": 876 + "val1": 654 + "val1": 676
        "val2": 4644, // "val1": 3456 + "val1": 300 + "val1": 888

        "data": [
          {
            "name": "shahnshah",
            "data": [
              {
                "name": "test1",
                "values": {
                  "val1": 876,
                  "val2": 3456
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
    },
    {
     // next object continued here
    }
  ]
```

This way I want to able to show the sum of the values at the top and can eventually display this in a nested table.

Comment: this is not free code writing service... You have to show us your attempt.

Comment: @Nur Thanks for letting me know, I didn't know this earlier

Answer (score 0):

```js
const collection = [
    {
      "name": "Top1",
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "shahnshah",
          "data": [
            {
              "name": "test1",
              "values": {
                "val1": 876,
                "val2": 3456
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Alex",
          "data": [
            {
              "name": "test1",
              "values": {
                "val1": 654,
                "val2": 300
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "test2",
              "values": {
                "val1": 676,
                "val2": 888
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Top2",
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "shahnshah",
          "data": [
            {
              "name": "test1",
              "values": {
                "val1": 111,
                "val2": 300
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Alex",
          "data": [
            {
              "name": "test1",
              "values": {
                "val1": 100,
                "val2": 150
              }
            },
            {
              "name": "test2",
              "values": {
                "val1": 600,
                "val2": 50
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

let newCollection=collection.reduce((a,c)=>{
 
 
c.val1=c.data.reduce((a1,c1)=>{  return a1+c1.data.reduce((aa,cc)=> aa+cc.values.val1,0);},0)
c.val2=c.data.reduce((a1,c1)=>{  return a1+c1.data.reduce((aa,cc)=> aa+cc.values.val2,0);},0)
 

a=[...a,c];
return a;
},[])

 
console.log(newCollection);
```